# How many background layers exist behind every CSS box?

Tags: html, css

Behind every CSS box is a specialized layer called the background layer. exactly how many background layers exist in every CSS box?

I would like to know that, exactly how many background layers exist behind every CSS box?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the answer is essentially **"1 background color + `n` specified background images"**.

[The specification is:](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds/#backgrounds)

> Each box has a background layer that may be fully transparent (the default), or filled with a color and/or one or more images. The background properties specify what color (background-color) and images (background-image) to use, and how they are sized, positioned, tiled, etc.
>
> The background properties are not inherited, but the parent box’s background will shine through by default because of the initial transparent value on background-color.
>
> The background of a box can have multiple background image layers. The number of layers is determined by the number of comma-separated values in the background-image property. Note that a value of none still creates a layer.

An "additional" layer is available if `border-image` is used

> NOTE: The border-image properties can also define a background image, which, if present, is **painted on top of the background layers** created by the background properties.

Answer (score -1):

it depends on how many bg images you have specified

```
.box {
  background-image: url(image1.png), url(image2.png);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

in the above there are 3 bg layers